# How can i print the value of variables(next,prev,current,currentNext) in each iteration in java?

Tags: java

I am writing reverse a linked list logic  but i want the values of variables in each iteration.
So,i can print the value??
Because i am trying to print like this System.out.println(current.data);
Then i am getting null pointer exception.
So,i can i resolve it or print the values.

```
 Node reverse(Node node)
{
    Node prev = null;
    Node current = node;
    Node next = null;
    while (current != null) {
        next = current.next;
        current.next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
        
        System.out.print(node.data+"R");
        System.out.println(current.data+"S");
        System.out.print(current.next.data);
    }
    node = prev;
    return node;
}
```

Comment: For the loop to exit, `current` has to be `null` at the point where you're trying to print `current.data`.  So you're guaranteed to either hit a NullPointerException or to get stuck in an infinite loop.  Why are you printing `node.data` inside the loop?  That value will never change, so you'll be printing the same value over and over.  Maybe you need to add some checks for `null` so that you only print values that actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

Print the data at the start of the loop to guarantee that `current` is not null.

```java
Node reverse(Node node)
{
    Node prev = null;
    Node current = node;
    Node next = null;
    while (current != null) {
        System.out.print(node.data+"R");
        System.out.println(current.data+"S");
        System.out.print(current.next.data);
        next = current.next;
        current.next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    node = prev;
    return node;
}
```

NPE is because you are printing the current data **AFTER** setting the current node to the next, and that is undesirable since you don't know if it's null.